# USB 3.1 Type C Adapter MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I want to know if there is any possibility to connect an USB 3.1 Type C device to a MacBook Pro Retina Early 2015. Is there any Thunderbold/USB 3.1 adaper?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's adapters all over the place.  Look at Amazon (I found [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YT688U0) for about $7 US) and Monoprice.

[image]

[image]